# How to get GCC Built-in Functions definition?

Tags: gcc, built-in

I want to get GCC Built-in Functions definition. I have downloaded gcc-releases-gcc-8.5.0 source code. In the source code, I have found the source code corresponding with GCC Built-in Functions definition. However, several layers of nesting in the GCC Built-in Functions definition, and I want to get the GCC Built-in Functions definition directly.

For example, how can I get the function definition of __builtin_offsetof and __builtin_choose_expr?

Comment: `I have found the source code corresponding with GCC Built-in Functions definition` `I want to get the GCC Built-in Functions definition directly` I do not understand. So you found or not? If you have not, and there _are_ several layers of nesting and there is no "direct" function definition, because such "direct" definition just does not exists, what then? Is there a  `__builtin_offset`? Did you mean `__builtin_offsetof`?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I have found. The meaning of "direct" is that I want to get something like the builtin function__builtin_add(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned *sum)(If there is one). I can get the function definition like the following

`void __builtin_add(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned *sum) {
  *result = a + b;
}
`

  Yes, I mean '__builtin_offsetof'

Comment: But ther is no such thing. There is no such function. There is `if (function == "__builtin_add") { code(); code(); }`. A function _definition_ does not exists - there is compiler code written inside the compiler to handle the _string_ `__builtin_add` specially with special code. It is not a real function.

Comment: _I want to get GCC Built-in Functions definition_ - for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Compiler code that handles __builtin_offsetof starts here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.cc#L9824 :

```
case RID_OFFSETOF:
  {
    c_parser_consume_token (parser);
    matching_parens parens;
    if (!parens.require_open (parser))
    ... etc ...
```

__builtin_choose_expr starts here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.cc#L9920 :

```
case RID_CHOOSE_EXPR:
  {
    vec<c_expr_t, va_gc> *cexpr_list;
    c_expr_t *e1_p, *e2_p, *e3_p;
    ... etc ...
```

The built-in functions in GCC are handled as C reserved words. The list of C reserved words in GCC is in here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c-family/c-common.cc#L385 . Lexer with the keywords looks like is initialized here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/cp/lex.cc#L252 .

Comment: Yes. __builtin_offsetof and __builtin_choose_expr starts from here [https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/c/c-parser.cc). However, I can get the function definition directly.

Comment: These parse C/C++ code into intermediate representation, but don't define the built-in functions. Do they?

Answer (score 0):

*Built-in functions* are those, which cannot be defined as (`always_inline`) functions in header files. *Built-in functions* aren't C-preprocessor *macros* expanding into C/C++ code. That's the reason they are called *built-in*.

A compiler parses the code into an intermediate representation. That intermediate representation encodes expressions, like a call to function `__builtin_offsetof` with these particular arguments.

Machine code gets generated from this intermediate representation and this is where function inlining and replacing calls to library functions with built-ins (or not) happens (depending on compiler options specified).

There are no C/C++ definitions for built-in functions - they get emitted as assembly language for a specific CPU/ISA in the compiler back-end, depending on compiler options specified.