# How is the built-in function of GCC implemented? Is there any corresponding source code? Such as __builtin_offsetof

Tags: gcc, built-in

In the process of looking at the code, I see the built-in function  __builtin_offsetof  of the compiler and then I can't see the implementation inside, and I am very interested in how the underlying layer of the code is implemented，anyone can help me ?

I tried searching online
[How to get GCC Built-in Functions definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76604807/how-to-get-gcc-built-in-functions-definition)
There is a related answer, but it still does not solve my problem, I do not see the source code implementation of the __builtin_offsetof in the answer

Comment: How do you not see it? What do you mean? I updated the answer to newer gcc version and added code blocks.

Comment: There is no *plain code* behind the implementation of `__builtin_offsetof`, there is the compiler constructing code to generate the underlying instructions for the operation. This is why it's called `builtin`, the compiler builds-in the code for the operation into the source there and then.

Comment: I apologize for not expressing my thoughts clearly. What I meant was that while browsing the project's code, I came across the function "_builtin_offsetof". After doing some research, I understand the function of __builtin_offsetof . However, I am curious about how its internal source code is implemented. I would appreciate it if I could find some relevant information on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw your updated answer